# change google map v3 click event to jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have this working code  :

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i)
            {
                return function ()
                {
                    infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                }
            })(marker, i));
```

howEver , I want to  change it to jQuery.

I tried , but with no success.

```
  $(google.maps.event).on('click', marker, function ()
  {
    (function (marker, i)
    {
      return function ()
      {
        infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      }
    })(marker, i)
  });
```

any help ?

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript. Why do you want to change it?

Comment: @Blazemonger cause i want to make things simple.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to treat `google.maps.event` as a DOM element, which it isn't. `.addListener` is a method unique to the Google Maps API and can't be controlled by jQuery.

However, there are several jQuery plugins designed to make manipulating the Google Maps API easier. I myself have recently used [gMap 2](http://labs.mario.ec/jquery-gmap/) with great success. A Google search for "jquery plugin google maps" will return many similar plugins, including [one of Google's own](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/).